# Как использовать Атрибуты в Design для кастомных View

Tags: android, view

XML

```
    <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="shapeDeclare">
        <attr name="shape" format="enum">
            <enum name="circle" value="0"/>
            <enum name="triangle" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Java

```
public class ShapeView extends TextView {
public ShapeView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.shapeDeclare,0, 0);

    try {
        Integer circle = a.getInteger(R.styleable.shapeDeclare_shape, 0);
        Integer triangle = a.getInteger(R.styleable.shapeDeclare_shape, 1);
    } finally { a.recycle(); }
}

public ShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
}
```

Это мой кастомный View, скажите как сделать чтобы в androidMaket можно было использовать переключения в Design, а то приходиться атрибуты указывать в самом XML, а мне хотелось бы как стандартные View через Design.

Comment: В смысле, чтобы в визуальном редакторе эти атрибуты отображались в свойствах ?

Comment: @pavlofff, да я про визуал говорил, а что знаете как?

Comment: [Судя по всему](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072453/does-android-studio-layout-editor-shows-custom-view-properties) на данный момент так сделать нельзя.